# Trying to put a border to all PDF pages throws an IO.Exception

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I have an existing pdf file with multiple pages to which I would like to put a border to all pages.

So I create a class that inherits from PdfPageEventHelper and I override the OnEndPage and assign the instance of that class to the PageEvent of PdfWriter instance:

```
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;

namespace My.Apps.WPF.Classes
{
    public class PdfEventHelper : PdfPageEventHelper
    {
        public override void OnEndPage(PdfWriter writer, iTextSharp.text.Document document)
        {
            // Add border to page
            PdfContentByte content = writer.DirectContent;
            iTextSharp.text.Rectangle rectangle = new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(document.PageSize);
            rectangle.Left += document.LeftMargin;
            rectangle.Right -= document.RightMargin;
            rectangle.Top -= document.TopMargin;
            rectangle.Bottom += document.BottomMargin;
            content.SetColorStroke(BaseColor.BLACK);
            content.Rectangle(rectangle.Left, rectangle.Bottom, rectangle.Width, rectangle.Height);
            content.Stroke();
        }
    }
}
```

Then in main program I have a method that returns a new PDF with a border in all its pages (source pdf document 'pdfFilePath' is in landscape, so I keep orientation in new one):

```
private string PutBorderToPdfPages(string pdfFilePath)
{
    string newPdf = @"C:\Output.pdf";

    using (var reader = new PdfReader(pdfFilePath))
    {
        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(newPdf, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            iTextSharp.text.Document document = new iTextSharp.text.Document(reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1));
            PdfEventHelper pdfEvent = new PdfEventHelper();

            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, fileStream);
            writer.PageEvent = pdfEvent;

            document.Open();

            document.Close(); // here it crashes, see below in post exception thrown
            writer.Close();
        }
    }

    return newPdf;
}
```

In run-time, in line:

```
document.Close();
```

I get an IO.Exception that says:

> The document has no pages.

In this case, Pdf document has only 1 page.

What am I doing wrong? I do not want to write anything to the existing pdf file, I only want to create a new PDF file exactly the same as source but with a border in all its pages.

**UPDATE**:

**ATTEMPT #1**:

I have done below, but I get all page in black (I do not know how to do the rectangle not filled):

```
private string PutBorderToPdfPages(string pdfFilePath)
{
    string newPdf = @"C:\Output.pdf";

    using (var reader = new PdfReader(pdfFilePath))
    {
        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(newPdf, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            using (var pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(reader, fileStream))
            {
                int PageCount = reader.NumberOfPages;   

                for (int p = 1; p <= PageCount; p++)
                {
                    // Add border to page                                
                    PdfContentByte cb = pdfStamper.GetOverContent(p);
                    iTextSharp.text.Rectangle rectangle = pdfReader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(p);
                    rectangle.BackgroundColor = iTextSharp.text.BaseColor.BLACK;                                
                    cb.Rectangle(rectangle);
                }                            
            }
        }
    }

    return newPdf;
}
```

**ATTEMPT #2**:

In this attempt, I get an ObjectDisposedException:

> Cannot access to a closed file.

when exiting the using of pdfStamper:

```
private string PutBorderToPdfPages(string pdfFilePath)
{
    string newPdf = @"C:\Output.pdf";

    using (var reader = new PdfReader(pdfFilePath))
    {
        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(newPdf, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        {
                    iTextSharp.text.Document document = new iTextSharp.text.Document(reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1));                        
                    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, fileStream);

                    document.Open();

                    using (var pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(reader, fileStream))
                    {                            
                        for (int p = 0; p < pdfStamper.Reader.NumberOfPages; p++)                            
                        {
                            // Add border to page
                            PdfContentByte content = writer.DirectContent;
                            iTextSharp.text.Rectangle rectangle = new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(document.PageSize);
                            rectangle.Left += document.LeftMargin;
                            rectangle.Right -= document.RightMargin;
                            rectangle.Top -= document.TopMargin;
                            rectangle.Bottom += document.BottomMargin;
                            content.SetColorStroke(iTextSharp.text.BaseColor.BLACK);
                            content.Rectangle(rectangle.Left, rectangle.Bottom, rectangle.Width, rectangle.Height);
                            content.Stroke();
                        }
                        document.Close();
                        writer.Close();
                    }
        }
    }

    return newPdf;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do

```
document.Open();

document.Close(); // here it crashes, see below in post exception thrown
```

I.e. you start a new document, add nothing to it, and then close it. Thus, it would be empty which iText responds to with `The document has no pages.`

Thus, the exception is completely correct.

---

The correct way to *"put a border to all pages"* of *"an existing pdf file"* is to

- open the document in a `PdfReader`,
- create a `PdfStamper` operating on that `PdfReader`,
- iterate over the pages of it and add borders,
- and close the `PdfStamper`.

E.g. like this for a source file `source` and a target file `dest`:

```
using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(source))
using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileStream(dest, FileMode.Create)))
{
    for (int pageNumber = 1; pageNumber <= reader.NumberOfPages; pageNumber++)
    {
        Rectangle cropBox = reader.GetCropBox(pageNumber);
        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(cropBox);
        rectangle.Left += 20;
        rectangle.Right -= 20;
        rectangle.Top -= 20;
        rectangle.Bottom += 20;

        PdfContentByte content = stamper.GetOverContent(pageNumber);
        content.SetColorStroke(iTextSharp.text.BaseColor.BLACK);
        content.Rectangle(rectangle.Left, rectangle.Bottom, rectangle.Width, rectangle.Height);
        content.Stroke();
    }
}
```

Comment: Our answers crossed each other ;-)

Comment: @BrunoLowagie nearly like the comments to the deleted nonsense answer... ;)

Comment: @mkl ok, I have done, but as I have the code that create the border on the overrided method OnEndPage, once I iterate over the pdf pages, how can I raise OnEndPage? I would like to use OnEndPage. So when iterate over each page using pdfStamper I do not write anything to the page (this should be done by OnEndPage).

Comment: *"I would like to use `OnEndPage`"* - Probably you would but that does not make sense: page events are triggered when *creating new* pages using a `Document` and a basic `PdfWriter` but in your context *no new pages are created!* Thus, pull your code from that page event handler into a loop over the pages and let it draw on the respective page's overcontent.

Comment: @user1624552 Take a look at [this FAQ item](https://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-watermark-pdfs-using-text-or-images). Sure, it's about adding a watermark to an existing document, but the same principle can be used to add a border.

Comment: @mkl Ok, see my update. I have moved the code in attempt #2. I have done two attempts but without success.

Comment: @user1624552 Don't use a `Document`. Don't use a `PdfWriter`. Instead use the `PdfStamper`. Don't use a `DirectContent`. Use the `OverContent`.

Comment: @user1624552 So your attempt #1 was nearly ok. You merely used the wrong `PdfContentByte.Rectangle` overload: The one you used is meant for drawing rectangular boxes with filled interior while you only want to stroke the outline. This overload has been a challenge for many other users, too... ;)

Comment: @mkl Your example is working perfecly. Great support. Thx!

Answer (score 4):

The **The document has no pages** error is thrown because you create a document that has no pages. It's as simple as that.

Look at your code:

```
Document document = new Document(reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1));
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, fileStream);
document.Open();
document.Close();
```

You aren't adding any content between `document.Open();` and `document.Close();`

Change it to:

```
Document document = new Document(reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1));
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, fileStream);
document.Open();
document.Add(new Paragraph("Some content"));
document.Close();
```

The error will disappear. If you don't want to add any content to the document, then... what's the point in creating the document?

**Extra remark:** I see that you create a document with a page size that is taken from another document: `reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1)`. What's your purpose? If you want to copy a page from another document, you are doing it wrong! You should use `PdfStamper` instead; that is, if you insist on working with an old version of iText.

**The real solution:** upgrade to iText 7, and you won't have this problem.

Comment: The page of the new pdf document (with borders in all its pages) should habe the same page size, so I do it. Isn't it correct? Sorry I am new to ITextSharp... The new document should keep the same pages orientation.I cannot change to a new version of ITextSharp now, for sure later, but not now.

Comment: See @mkl's answer. What you describe, needs to be done using `PdfStamper`.

Comment: See my last update. I have done two different attempts without success.

Comment: Ouch... You're making some brutal errors. If iText were my child (which in a way it is), I wouldn't let you take care of it.

Answer (score 0):

The question underwent some significant changes, so instead of updating my initial answer (which I consider to be the correct answer to the initial question), I'll post a new answer in reply to the updated question.

You are mixing `PdfWriter` code with `PdfStamper` code, and that's wrong. When you create a `PdfStamper` instance, you *automatically* create a `PdfWriter` instance internally.

This is wrong:

```
using (var reader = new PdfReader(pdfFilePath))
{
    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(newPdf, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
    {
        Document document = new Document(reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1));                        
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, fileStream);
        document.Open();
        using (var pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(reader, fileStream))
        {                            
            for (int p = 0; p < pdfStamper.Reader.NumberOfPages; p++)                            
            {
                // Add border to page
                PdfContentByte content = writer.DirectContent;
                Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(document.PageSize);
                rectangle.Left += document.LeftMargin;
                rectangle.Right -= document.RightMargin;
                rectangle.Top -= document.TopMargin;
                rectangle.Bottom += document.BottomMargin;
                content.SetColorStroke(iTextSharp.text.BaseColor.BLACK);
                content.Rectangle(rectangle.Left, rectangle.Bottom, rectangle.Width, rectangle.Height);
                content.Stroke();
            }
            document.Close();
            writer.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Please try this:

```
using (var reader = new PdfReader(pdfFilePath))
{
    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(newPdf, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
    {
        using (var pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(reader, fileStream))
        {                            
            for (int p = 1; p <= reader.NumberOfPages; p++)                            
            {
                // Add border to page
                PdfContentByte content = pdfStamper.GetOverContent(p);
                Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(pdfReader.GetPageSize(p));
                rectangle.Left += margin;
                rectangle.Right -= margin;
                rectangle.Top -= margin;
                rectangle.Bottom += margin;
                content.SetColorStroke(iTextSharp.text.BaseColor.BLACK);
                content.Rectangle(rectangle.Left, rectangle.Bottom, rectangle.Width, rectangle.Height);
                content.Stroke();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *"Please try this"* - You (appropriately) removed the `Document document` but the code still uses `document.LeftMargin` etc. You initially use `reader` for the `PdfReader`, then `pdfReader`.

Comment: OK, I replaced those parameters with just `margin` assuming that the `margin` parameter is defined somewhere before the snippet starts.