# How to add border in all PDF pages using c#

Tags: c#, itext

I want to add border into my all pages in PDF using ItextSharp but it set only last page of PDF byte.

Here is my code :

```
   if (Document Doc is null   || PDFWriter Writer is null)
        {
            throw new NullReferenceException();
        }

        //Add border to page
        PdfContentByte content = Writer.DirectContent;
        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(Doc.PageSize);
        rectangle.Left += Doc.LeftMargin;
        rectangle.Right -= Doc.RightMargin;
        rectangle.Top -= Doc.TopMargin;
        rectangle.Bottom += Doc.BottomMargin;
        content.SetColorStroke(BaseColor.Black);
        content.Rectangle(rectangle.Left, rectangle.Bottom, rectangle.Width, rectangle.Height);
        content.Stroke();
```

Comment: Your code is too incomplete. What exactly e.g. is `Writer`? Is it a plain `PdfWriter`? Or for some `PdfStamper stamper` the `stamper.Writer`? And what have you done yet with your `Doc` and `Writer`?

Comment: @mkl I have update my question

Comment: Ok. While the syntax is invalid, you appear to express that `Writer` is a plain `PdfWriter`. As you say that the border appears only on the last page, I assume you call the code above *after* all content has been added to the `Document`. But this is too late, previous pages at that point in time have already been written to the output stream. Instead you should use a page event listener to draw the border on each page as soon as it's nearly finished.

Comment: Ohhk Thank you @mkl. Can you please provide me some minimal code or suggest any article ?

Comment: Does my answer solve your question? Then please accept the answer. Otherwise please illustrate your open issues with it.

Answer (score 1):

You create a new document using a `Document`/`PdfWriter` couple and want to add some decoration (be it a border as in your case, or header or footer texts, or some background graphic, ...) to each and every page. The most common (and usually the only reliable) way to do this is by using page events, e.g. in your case you can use this page event listener:

```cs
public class Border : PdfPageEventHelper
{
    public override void OnEndPage(PdfWriter Writer, Document Doc)
    {
        PdfContentByte content = Writer.DirectContent;
        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(Doc.PageSize);
        rectangle.Left += Doc.LeftMargin;
        rectangle.Right -= Doc.RightMargin;
        rectangle.Top -= Doc.TopMargin;
        rectangle.Bottom += Doc.BottomMargin;
        content.SetColorStroke(BaseColor.BLACK);
        content.Rectangle(rectangle.Left, rectangle.Bottom, rectangle.Width, rectangle.Height);
        content.Stroke();
    }
}
```

like this

```cs
using (Document document = new Document())
{
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, DESTINATION_STREAM);
    writer.PageEvent = new Border();
    document.Open();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        document.Add(new Paragraph("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet."));
    }
}
```

The result:

[image: Screen shot]

---

If you otherwise want to add a border to an existing PDF, you do so using a `PdfReader`/`PdfStamper` couple as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48148665/1729265).

Comment: @Sachin *"Its working"* - great! In that case please accept the answer (click the tick at its upper left, below the up arrow, the votes number, and the down arrow).